# Why does ActiveRecord select every single association to update a single column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

Why does *EVERY* single `belongs_to` association need to be selected first just to call `update!`? This seems a bit ridiculous, and I don't remember this being like that before, maybe I was using a deprecated method or something.

I know there is `update_attribute` which doesn't have this problem, but I want to update multiple attributes at once using a bang method.

I have some records with 5 associations, and just to update one or two columns it automatically does...

```
SELECT * FROM a
SELECT * FROM b
SELECT * FROM c
SELECT * FROM d
SELECT * FROM e
UPDATE f
```

I also am not using any validations at all, nor `validates_associated`

Model:

```rb
class Lead < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :prospect
  belongs_to :visit
  belongs_to :session
  has_one    :result

  enum status: [
    'PENDING',
    'COMPLETE',
  ]

end
```

and

```
lead = Lead.first
lead.update!(status: 1)
```

```
[8] pry(main)> s.update!(slug: 'x')   
TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN   
Campaign Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" WHERE "campaigns"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "76dfe777-f563-43b1-900b-a2c40ea7d072"], ["LIMIT", 1]]   
Sequence Update (0.6ms)  UPDATE "sequences" SET "slug" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "sequences"."id" = $3  [["slug", "x"], ["updated_at", "2023-01-27 01:49:32.472637"], ["id", "19c41977-71c6-4c60-a6b6-7af6ce090d80"]]   
TRANSACTION (0.7ms)  COMMIT => true
```

All columns look like this:

```
t.references :prospect, null: false, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing? You haven't actually showed the method that you're calling, you haven't shown the model configuration, you haven't explained what objects are being changed. Please explain both your inputs and expected outputs as well as the actual outputs that you're getting, and please explain what the actual problem is in the behavior.

Comment: It's quite literally the simplest case imaginable. I have a model with 5 belong_to association, no extra fancy features, and no validations. In fact associations and a single enum is the only code in the model. I cannot call thing.update!(status: 1) without 5 selects before the UPDATE query. The problem in behavior is... why does it need to validate not just the presence of the ID but selecting the full record.

Comment: The only thing out of the ordinary in the database migration is that it's using a UUID primary key, but I don't know why that should make a difference.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you think it's literally the simplest case imaginable. That should make it very easy to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You have not included an MRE. I have a Rails 7 app with a nearly identical model. `update!(foo: 'bar')` does not eager load associated records. Therefore your example is incomplete and it is not possible to answer your question because you have chosen not to include the information necessary to reproduce the issue even after being asked for it and directed to resources explaining why. You should ask yourself why your comments were nuked and why your question was closed by a moderator. It might be because the person that offered to help in your time of need was met with a tirade of insults.

Comment: What I put is literally what is in my code. It's occurring in every single model of my app. The only different things than default rails I can think of... its in API mode. Im using UUID PKs.

Comment: `[8] pry(main)> s.update!(slug: 'x')
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Campaign Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" WHERE "campaigns"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "76dfe777-f563-43b1-900b-a2c40ea7d072"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Sequence Update (0.6ms)  UPDATE "sequences" SET "slug" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "sequences"."id" = $3  [["slug", "x"], ["updated_at", "2023-01-27 01:49:32.472637"], ["id", "19c41977-71c6-4c60-a6b6-7af6ce090d80"]]
  TRANSACTION (0.7ms)  COMMIT
=> true`

Comment: @anothermh in your schema, do you have something similar to this (ie null false)? `t.references :sequence, null: false, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid`

Comment: I also have UUIDs with the same constraint. I also have the app in API only mode. I have a pretty good idea of where to look now that you’ve posted the actual outputs. But like I said, I’m unwilling to help you because you called me stupid. Best of luck.

Comment: It recommend add the extra details from the comment, work in a minimal example with everything needed for others to test, and delete all your comments where you discuss who has the skill to answer. If you do those, you will have a much higher chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`belongs_to` associations are *required* by default, which automatically adds presence validation.

> **:required**
> When set to `true`, the association will also have its
> presence validated. This will validate the association itself, not the
> id. You can use `:inverse_of` to avoid an extra query during validation.
> NOTE: `required` is set to `true` by default and is deprecated. If you
> don't want to have association presence validated, use `optional: true`.

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to*

I don't know what `:inverse_of` is supposed to do in this situation, doesn't seem to do anything.

Let's say you have this model:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

*belongs_to* adds a presence validator:

```rb
>> Post.validators
=> [#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x00007f1fa2e96c40 @attributes=[:user], @options={:message=>:required}>]
```

In short, it does [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.2/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb#L7) to validate *user*: `post.user.blank?`, which loads the association.

You can set association as optional:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end

>> Post.validators
=> []
```

and add your own validations if you want:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true

  validates :user,    presence: true, on: :create
  validates :user_id, presence: true, on: :update
end
```

Which only sort of works and breaks in some situations.

It will probably be best to handle it outside of the model with a custom validator and just skip model validations.

---

To update multiple attributes:

```rb
post = Post.first
post.assign_attributes(title: "name")
post.save!(validate: false)
```

---

There is also a config:
*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-active-record-belongs-to-required-by-default*

Comment: Ah interesting, yeah I saw inverse_false and that doesn't make sense clearly what that is even doing that can't be inferred from looking at the class names, etc. I love the assign_attributes way though, didn't even think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm perhaps an even better option is... config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false in config